# What am I missing in my OS X Squirrel configuration?

Tags: macos, electron-builder

I'm deploying an Electron app with Squirrel on the backend to do updates.  The Windows deployment works just fine, updating from a .nupkg at this sample path:

```
https://host/update/win32/1.0.1/RELEASES
```

However, the Mac version (which I'm supplying a .zip file to as per the docs) does not seem to work.  I've run across some contradictory information on the pathing (and have tried them all, plus a great many variations in case there were typos in the docs), but the very latest info I could find is what I'm using now:

```
https://host/update/darwin_x64/1.0.1
```

What path should I be using for OS X?  Is there perhaps something about the .zip file that Electron-builder (with the Squirrel module) is creating that might be causing a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code signing environment variables were not getting properly set in my OS X build script, so code signing was not happening.  In order for OS X apps to update via Squirrel, both the new and the old versions MUST be signed.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is tagged as electron-builder. electron-builder supports server-less and simple [auto-update](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/wiki/Auto-Update).